# Swift NSDateFormatter return a strange year 0005 instead 2023

Tags: swift, datetimeformatter

I am using very simple date format but some devices returning a wrong year. This only happened on 1 device in Japan so I could not reproduce it.

```
let timeStamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970

let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timeStamp)
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current
dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
let result = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

print(result)
```

The result is `0005-10-13`

Anh help!

Comment: `timeStamp/1000.0`, why??? And stop using NS types when there are native swift types

Comment: "happened on 1 device in Japan", locale perhaps? You can test by switching your emulator/device region. I suspect you're using legacy code translated to Swift and somewhere else either a parsing/conversion choke on it. FWIW, this is Reiwa 5 in Japanese calendar, as in fifth year of Emperor Naruhito reign

Comment: You should __always__ set the `Locale` of the `DateFormatter` when working with hardcoded `dateFormat`s, since a hardcoded date format might not be meaningful in some locales.

Comment: You are getting the “time interval” (literally defined as # of seconds since the reference date) dividing it by 1,000, and and then using that strange value (how many thousands of seconds) as a time interval parameter, which, again, is looking for seconds.

Comment: That having been said, I wonder if this “divide by 1000” problem is one that you introduced when composing the question, because that simply won't work on *any* device. If you have a problem that occurs only on particular devices in particular counties, then that is more likely a problem with locale, where users might be using non-Gregorian calendars. See localization discussion in `DateFormatter` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the issue. If device set calendar to Japan this issue will happen. To fix it just add like below.

```
dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
```

Thank to @Martheen

Comment: Yeah, you should always explicitly request a Gregorian calendar if that's what you are expecting in your code. (It's reasonable, and even recommended, to use the user's local Calendar to display dates. Somebody in China, Japan, or Israel might want to see their dates in their local (non-gregorian calendar)